# Azure - fail running external EXE

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am running a WebApi on Azure, in one of the request I need to run an external EXE, and return by its running result.

It works perfect on my local machine.

- the exe reads a file, process it, and write the result to a new file to the local storage.
- I have writing privileges (done writing of file and directory before)
- I doubled checked the paths and the existence of the resources
- all the paths look ok - example: `D:\home\\site\wwwroot\myexe.exe`

here is the call:

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();

si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
si.UseShellExecute = false;
si.CreateNoWindow = true;

si.FileName = _pathToExe;
si.Arguments = _prathToArguments;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = si;

p.Start();

p.WaitForExit();
```

when debugging it I noticed that the process "completes" right away, and doesn't preform his work.

What am I missing? Am I allowed to run in this way an exe Azure? or should I use Work Role?

Thanks!!

Comment: A few questions ... are you sure the EXE is being deployed to your cloud service? You can RDP in to check. Is there a hard coded path in the EXE? The file system is definitely different in a cloud service.

Comment: Yes sir. all the required resources are deployed (double checked that). the EXE runs a script (which is also deployed) that was modified to the resources' new paths.